# Is there any way to prevent virtual smartphone keyboard hiding input?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, virtual-keyboard

On my mobile site (I use jQuery Mobile) I have inputs at the bottom of the page. When I try to input some info to it virtual keyboard appears (as it must do). And problem is that it hides a half of the page including input where I'm typing instead of the page scrolling up. In the example inputs 4-8 are hidden under the keyboard.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="1">
<input type="text" placeholder="2">
<input type="text" placeholder="3">
<input type="text" placeholder="4">
<input type="text" placeholder="5">
<input type="text" placeholder="6">
<input type="text" placeholder="7">
<input type="text" placeholder="8">
```

**CSS**

```
input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: How would you like it to show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used jQuery.mobile.silentScroll() for this, on the input focus event, and then scroll back down on blur.

Something like this:

```
          $('#myinput').on('focus',function(){
                $.mobile.silentScroll($('#myinput').position().top - 100);
                $('#myinput').focus();
            });
            $('#myinput').on('blur',function(){
                $.mobile.silentScroll($('#myform').position().top);
            });
```